# Distance & Direction of Longitude & Latitude relative to a center point

Tags: javascript, math, latitude-longitude, geo

I have Latitude & Longitude of my own position.
I have Latitude & Longitude of some other positions (Max=50Km away).
I have an Image ( width: 250px, height: 250px )
I now want myself to be the center of the image, and all other points to be shown around me. I don't filter device heading (degree relative to true north), because it must be able to calculate the distance AND direction realtive to image width and height.

I want the pixels where to display the Avatar-Image of all other Points in Range 50Km.

```
+---------------------------+
+------               ------+
+-----                 -----+
+----  [OTHER1]         ----+
+---                     ---+
+--                       --+
+-                         -+
+           [ME]            +
+-                         -+
+--                       --+
+---                     ---+
+----         [OTHER2]  ----+
+-----                 -----+
+------               ------+
+---------------------------+
[ME]     = Lat: 52.3796664, Lon: 9.7614715
[OTHER1] = Lat: 52.653042, Lon: 9.380040
[OTHER2] = Lat: 51.648683, Lon: 10.945592
```

I guess that's sooooo easy but I was thinking, googling about it 6 hours by now. Please anyone... help me.

Thank you

Btw.: Code please in Javascript, MySql or Php (Doesn't matter if I do it Server or Client-Side. Or just a formular.)